# Removing specular reflection from image

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I'm trying to remove specular reflection from a ring light from my image. I want to remove specular reflection from both the test image and the flat image before performing flat-field correction. Here are the two images:

[Test Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tMsFt.png) 
[Flat / Background Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCY4w.png)

The light and the camera are placed directly above the flat object (changing geometry is not feasible). My understanding is that the signal received by the camera is the sum of diffused color and the specular reflection. So to estimate the reflection component, I placed a black surface (same material as the original object) and captured the reflected component. The black surface was captured as follows:

[Black image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cyNpg.png)

However, when I try to subtract it from my image, the ring shaped area in both the images become darker, which implies that the black surface had a stronger specular reflection component than both the test image and the flat image. After subtraction of specular component, the image looks like this:

[Specular free image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ljc6z.png)

Can someone tell me why is that?

Comment: Black image = diffuse reflection + specular reflection. It's not just specular reflection. You need to remove the black intensity before using it for correction. Then you also need to make sure that the camera settings don't change (automatic gain/aperture/integration time adjustment?). Finally, if the surface has a different color, specular reflection might be changed also. You might have to create a more complex model to fit the specular reflection.

Comment: For the black surface, I assumed that the diffused reflection component would be zero, and verified that by checking the black intensity in areas where it wasn't directly under the light. As for camera settings, I turned off all automatic adjustments and captured raw images.

Comment: The change of color is another concern, but then I'll need to create a different model for different areas of the same object? I am trying to create a general model for this surface which models specular reflection as a function of spatial position!

Comment: which problem is it you actually want to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Reflectance is a function of wavelength. So is the sensitivity of your camera.

Any calibration done with a homogeneous reflectance target will fail on anything inhomogeneous. No matter if it's due to surface roughness or colour.

Also your image is terribly underexposed.